# Problem with AzureStorageEmulator.exe Azure SDK and Visual Studio related

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2019, azure-sdk

Premise: I'm a frontend web developer and I had to launch a project written in C# that has many dependencies. I tried to set the enviroment but I had many issues, this is one that neither I, nor the people around me, can resolve (at least we couldn't until now).

When I try to run the solution it always throws an error and open a popup where it writes something like "it is not possible run Azure storage emulator. Run AzureStorageEmulator.exe as administrator and try again". I tried to run the command but it tells me that it is not installed. I unistalled and installed again the Azure SDK, still the error, I installed the storage emulator from here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-emulator#using-sdk but nothing.

What can I do?
I'm using Visual Studio 2019, .net core 2.2 and Azure SDK

Sorry for my funny English, I'm not native.

Comment: You can download the standalone installer for storage emulator here https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=717179&clcid=0x409

Comment: Start your Command Prompt as Administrator. Paste this `cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\Storage Emulator` and hit enter. Once you're in the directory type `AzureStorageEmulator.exe start`. This will start the Azure storage emulator.